# Renderer more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm working on a project with bare expo and react native. I have implemented firebase to my project. The signIn and register are working fine. I have created a auth check to send the user to another page in case he is logged in. Although I am receiving the following error when attempting to send the user to another page:
[image]

This is my App.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import {
    useFonts,
    Poppins_400Regular,
    Poppins_500Medium,
    Poppins_700Bold
} from '@expo-google-fonts/poppins';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import theme from './src/global/styles/theme';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { AppRoutes } from './src/routes/app.routes';
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/pt-BR';
import { SignIn } from './src/screens/SignIn';
import auth, { FirebaseAuthTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function App() {

    const [ fontsLoaded ] = useFonts({
        Poppins_400Regular,
        Poppins_500Medium,
        Poppins_700Bold
    });
    const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null>(null);

    if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return <AppLoading />;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser);
        return subscriber;
    }, []);

  return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <StatusBar style="light"/>
            <NavigationContainer>
                { user ? <AppRoutes /> : <SignIn /> }
            </NavigationContainer>                      
        </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

This is the routes code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Dashboard } from '../screens/Dashboard';
import { Register } from '../screens/Register';
import { useTheme } from 'styled-components';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Summary } from '../screens/Summary';
 
const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator();

export function AppRoutes() {
    const theme = useTheme();

    return (
        <Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.orange,
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme.colors.texts,
                tabBarLabelPosition: 'beside-icon',
                tabBarStyle: {
                    height: 88,
                    paddingVertical: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 0
                }
            }}
        >
            <Screen 
                key="Listing"
                name="Listing"
                component={Dashboard}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({ size, color }) => 
                        <MaterialIcons 
                            name="format-list-bulleted"
                            size={size}
                            color={color}
                        /> 
                    )
                }}
            />
            <Screen
                key="Register"
                name="Register"
                component={Register}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({ size, color }) => 
                        <MaterialIcons 
                            name="attach-money"
                            size={size}
                            color={color}
                        /> 
                    )
                }}
            />
            <Screen 
                key="Summary"
                name="Summary"
                component={Summary}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: (({ size, color }) => 
                        <MaterialIcons 
                            name="pie-chart"
                            size={size}
                            color={color}
                        /> 
                    )
                }}
            />
        </Navigator>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue comes from this block:

```
if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
}

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser);
    return subscriber;
}, []);
```

You are conditionally adding a hook here, because if `fontsLoaded` evaluates to false, you return the render function earlier and the `useEffect` hook is never run at the first render. However, in subsequent attempts, the fonts are probably loaded, and this causes a different number of hooks being rendered: hence the error you get.

Based on react's own ["rules of hooks" guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), emphasis my own:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, **always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns**. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.

To fix this, simply ensure all hooks are defined before any `return` paths. In your case, this is done by swapping the `fontsLoaded` check:

```
// Define all hooks before any return paths!
useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser);
    return subscriber;
}, []);


if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
}

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <StatusBar style="light"/>
        <NavigationContainer>
            { user ? <AppRoutes /> : <SignIn /> }
        </NavigationContainer>                      
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

It is of course sometimes difficult to catch errors like this, especially in a heavy/complicated component. If you're using eslint, there is an eslint plugin called [`eslint-plugin-react-hook`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) that will cause eslint to throw a warning/error when this happens.